# OnClick item dont work on SQLite DB populated to list view

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, listview-adapter

I have tried to make this work, but it keeps redirecting me to the error page I created for the the webview activity.

The app is like a book app, I created the db for the "Add to Fav" tab, when the Add to Fav is clicked, it adds the current webview page "id" and "title" to the db, I'm trying to do it so that when the bookmark'd listview is clicked, it opens the URL.

The alert dialog works fine in the OnLongItemClick method.
please check the below code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener;

public class GoToFav extends Activity {
private GymsDbHelper mHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase dataBase;

private ArrayList<String> gymId = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayList<String> htitle = new ArrayList<String>();

private ListView gymList;
private AlertDialog.Builder build;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.favpage);
    gymList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.gymList);
    mHelper = new GymsDbHelper(this);

    gymList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            String name = htitle.get(position);
            if (name.equals("XXXXXX")) {
                Intent i = new Intent(GoToFav.this, WebViewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("keyHTML",
                        "file:///android_asset/gympage1.html");
                startActivity(i);

            } else {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        WebViewActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("keyHTML",
                        "file:///android_asset/yerrorpage.html");
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });

    // long click to delete data
    gymList.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int arg2, long arg3) {

            build = new AlertDialog.Builder(GoToFav.this);
            build.setTitle("Delete " + htitle.get(arg2));
            build.setMessage("Do you want to delete ?");
            build.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                    htitle.get(arg2) + " is deleted.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            dataBase.delete(
                                    GymsDbHelper.TABLE_NAME,
                                    GymsDbHelper.KEY_ID + "="
                                            + gymId.get(arg2), null);
                            displayData();
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            build.setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alert = build.create();
            alert.show();

            return true;
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    displayData();
    super.onResume();
}

/**
 * displays data from SQLite
 */
private void displayData() {
    dataBase = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "
            + GymsDbHelper.TABLE_NAME, null);

    gymId.clear();
    htitle.clear();
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            gymId.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(GymsDbHelper.KEY_ID)));
            htitle.add(mCursor.getString(mCursor
                    .getColumnIndex(GymsDbHelper.KEY_HTITLE)));

        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    FavAdapter favadpt = new FavAdapter(GoToFav.this, gymId, htitle);
    gymList.setAdapter(favadpt);
    mCursor.close();
}

}
```

Thank you!

Comment: It seems like `name.equals("XXXXXX")` fails. You probably have mixed up the data you stored, one way or another.

Comment: Besides I would also advice you to put the mCursor.close in a finally clause. Otherise if anything goes wrong your cursor is never closed and you have a resource leak.

Comment: Hey... thank you for that last bit, I have been on it since and I havent gotten anywhere with it, infact, right now, I'm just going to remove the onClick method for the listview items, and instead put the page number in the webView title, hence the "Add to Fav" works, but the user would need to go back and input the page number himself to open the right weBview. Poor but at this stage, thats just what I'm going to do. Thanks tho for the input, seems loads of users dont wanna help.